# Export files do not have carriage returns

Tags: export

I have Blender 2.77 installed on 2 vms, xubuntu 15.04 and win7. (Parallels 10). In the linux vm there are no problems with exporting -- everything works okay.  In the win vm I can only export .ply or .stl files in Ascii. If I try to export .obj or .fbx, the output files do not have carriage returns. (All options unchecked, z-axis up). Can someone tell me why this happens? (Zip version of Blender).

thanks,
Whiffee

Comment: Could you give some more details? What is the problem?

Comment: As an addition to the answer by @metaphor_set, [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) a longer explanation of the newline/carriage return problem, and why there are different conventions.

Comment: really, downvoting this is inappropriate - how do you expect the op to *know* that the cr/lf differences between windows and linux (unix) wasn't due to blender? Although this is ancient history, you'd not know this unless you've worked with ascii-based files across systems. So perhaps the op's work with blender *IS* the first time he's encountered this. Can we be nicer please?

Comment: @HowardPautz - it's **ongoing** history and common knowledge among most programmers, especially web developers. Please read Duane Dibbley's comment. Also, I don't understand either why it got DV'd.

Comment: @metaphor_set - not just web developer's ... every programmer will encounter this at some point ... I learned about it when unix programmers were chuckling over this thing called "DOS" :-P

Comment: @HowardPautz - yep. Add utf-8 and a web application project on different systems to that list. 10 years later and I still have nightmares...

Comment: @metaphor_set maybe I shouldn't laugh, but I had to chuckle ... I too have similar nightmares :0 ... And I hope a few others upvote it back to normal as it really is a valid question, although it's not a blender issue, the op *did* encounter it while using blender... how could he learn unless he asked!

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this is older than Blender itself and therefore not Blender-related. There's nothing wrong with your files, Windows and Unix/Linux based operating systems handle CR/LF differently.

Windows still uses the old MS-DOS "\r\n" while Unix/Linux uses "\n". You need either an editor that is capable of auto-detect the used format or (on GNU/Linux) try dos2unix to convert your files.

[Edit] Under the hood the Carriage Return + Linefeed ("\r\n") is actually 0D0A in ascii hexadecimal ... if you looked at the windows/dos created file with a hex editor.  A linux (unix) file would show just 0A.

Comment: I can't comment because I don't have any points. Just to say thanks for all the nice answers so quickly provided. The one thing I don't understand is why the .ply and .stl files look okay (in Wordpad) without any doctoring?

Comment: It all depends on how much effort and thought the developer of the exporters put into them. They might have used \r\n instead of just \n. Many Unix/Linux text editors are capable of detecting the line endings and adjust their settings accordingly. Basic MS stuff like Wordpad or Notepad doesn't take care of other formats. You might want to try advanced Windows editors like EditPad lite or similar....